# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid object type: 0

Tags: ignite

We have 16 machine production cluster and a partitioned cache. After restarting the cache, start to get/put and scan the cache we have a strange exception:

```
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to execute query on node [query=GridCacheQueryBean [qry=GridCacheQueryAdapter [type=SCAN, clsName=null, clause=null, filter=null, transform=null, part=422, incMeta=false, metrics=GridCacheQueryMetricsAdapter [minTime=9223372036854775807, maxTime=0, sumTime=0, avgTime=0.0, execs=0, completed=0, fails=0], pageSize=1024, timeout=0, incBackups=false, forceLocal=false, dedup=false, prj=null, keepBinary=false, subjId=dc87c308-db96-4c0a-a427-9a4387915f2b, taskHash=0, mvccSnapshot=null], rdc=null, trans=null], nodeId=f5046f7d-27f1-44dd-9b91-36af05664e1b]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.onPage(GridCacheQueryFutureAdapter.java:384)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.processQueryResponse(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:402)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.access$000(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:64)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$1.apply(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:94)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$1.apply(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:92)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1056)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:581)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$700(GridCacheIoManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$OrderedMessageListener.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1613)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1569)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4100(GridIoManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$GridCommunicationMessageSet.unwind(GridIoManager.java:2768)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.unwindMessageSet(GridIoManager.java:1529)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4400(GridIoManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$10.run(GridIoManager.java:1498)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid object type: 0
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cacheobject.IgniteCacheObjectProcessorImpl.toKeyCacheObject(IgniteCacheObjectProcessorImpl.java:166)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.binary.CacheObjectBinaryProcessorImpl.toKeyCacheObject(CacheObjectBinaryProcessorImpl.java:865)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.CacheDataRowAdapter.readFullRow(CacheDataRowAdapter.java:333)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.CacheDataRowAdapter.initFromLink(CacheDataRowAdapter.java:167)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.CacheDataRowAdapter.initFromLink(CacheDataRowAdapter.java:108)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.tree.DataRow.<init>(DataRow.java:55)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.tree.CacheDataRowStore.dataRow(CacheDataRowStore.java:92)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.tree.CacheDataTree.getRow(CacheDataTree.java:200)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.tree.CacheDataTree.getRow(CacheDataTree.java:49)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree$ForwardCursor.fillFromBuffer0(BPlusTree.java:5512)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree$AbstractForwardCursor.fillFromBuffer(BPlusTree.java:5280)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree$AbstractForwardCursor.nextPage(BPlusTree.java:5332)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree$ForwardCursor.next(BPlusTree.java:5566)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl$6.onHasNext(IgniteCacheOffheapManagerImpl.java:978)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.hasNextX(GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.java:53)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.GridIteratorAdapter.hasNext(GridIteratorAdapter.java:45)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager$ScanQueryIterator.advance(GridCacheQueryManager.java:2996)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager$ScanQueryIterator.onHasNext(GridCacheQueryManager.java:2965)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.hasNextX(GridCloseableIteratorAdapter.java:53)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.GridIteratorAdapter.hasNext(GridIteratorAdapter.java:45)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryManager.runQuery(GridCacheQueryManager.java:1266)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.processQueryRequest(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:234)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$2.apply(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:109)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheDistributedQueryManager$2.apply(GridCacheDistributedQueryManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1056)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:581)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:380)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:306)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$100(GridCacheIoManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:295)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1569)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1197)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4200(GridIoManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.run(GridIoManager.java:1093)
```

What can be the problem? The machines are virtual and the traffic is not so much on the cache.

Comment: Do you have some further information to make it more likely to be reproducible: Which version do you use? Is there any configuration you use you can share? etc.

Comment: CacheConfiguration<K, V> cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration<>();
        cacheConfiguration.setName("cacheName");
        cacheConfiguration.setEventsDisabled(true);
        cacheConfiguration.setStoreKeepBinary(true);
        cacheConfiguration.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
        cacheConfiguration.setBackups(1);cacheConfiguration.setGroupName(cacheType.getCacheGroupName());

Comment: And the version is 2.7.0, the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a corrupted data storage to me. Can you remove data storage from this node and re-add it to Baseline Topology? I hope that you have enough backups.